# Website content like " [sc_countdown year=”2019″ month=”1″ day=”1″ hour=”0″ minute=”0″

Tags: wordpress, web, wordpress-theming

Why a website is showing the content like:

```
[sc_countdown year=”2019″ month=”1″ day=”1″ hour=”0″ minute=”0″ bg_color=”#” num_color=”#ffffff” show_second=”1″ css_animation=”” animation_delay=””]
```

The whole page is showing content like this. It is based on WordPress and using a theme. Does anyone know why is this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a WordPress [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode). My guess is there is some sort of countdown plugin that you need to install in order for this content to display correctly. Or maybe the plugin you're trying to use is deprecated, so the shortcode isn't working anymore, and is instead just displaying as plain text on your page.

There are plenty of other [countdown plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/countdown/) you can install that will hopefully work for you.

Comment: did you change the theme? it seems that it came with a theme of ThemeMascot:
http://docs.kodesolution.info/wp/kb/sc-countdown-timer/
if you still got the same theme, check their documentation.